# Find an asymptotic formula for $\sum\limits_{n\leq x} d(n)\log n$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Please help me to find the asymptotics for the sum described above:

$$\sum\limits_{n\leq x} d(n)\log n.$$

This is a problem in analytic number theory.

Comment: Using Abel's summation theory and Dirichlet's theory

Comment: It would be better to describe your attempts to solve the problem, too.

Answer (score 4):

By the [Dirichlet's hyperbola method](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~m105f13/m105f13notes2.pdf) we have:
$$ \sum_{n\leq x}d(n) = x\log x+(2\gamma-1)x+O(\sqrt{x})$$
hence [Abel's summation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) gives:

$$\sum_{n\leq x}d(n)\log n = x\log^2 x+(2\gamma-1)x\log x-\int_{1}^{x}\left(\log u+(2\gamma-1)\right)\,du+O(\sqrt{x}\log x) $$
that simplifies to:
$$\sum_{n\leq x}d(n)\log n = x\log^2 x+(2\gamma-2)x\log x+O(x).$$

Comment: Very nice! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

First note that:
$$2\sum_{d\mid n}\log(d)=\sum_{d\mid n}\log(d)+\sum_{d\mid n}\log(\frac{n}{d})=\sum_{d\mid n}\log(n)=d(n)\log(n)$$
Then by the Dirichlet hyperbola method:
$$\sum_{n\leq x}d(n)\log(n)=-2\lfloor{\sqrt{x}}\rfloor\log(\lfloor{\sqrt{x}}\rfloor!)+2\sum_{n\leq \sqrt{x}}\log(n)\lfloor{\frac{x}{n}}\rfloor+\log(\lfloor{\frac{x}{n}}\rfloor!)$$
$$=O(\sqrt{x}\log(x))+2x-x\log(x)+2\sum_{n\leq \sqrt{x}}\frac{x}{n}\log(n)+
\frac{x}{n}\log(\frac{x}{n})-\frac{x}{n}$$
$$=O(\sqrt{x}\log(x))+2x-x\log(x)+2x(\log(x)-1)\sum_{n\leq \sqrt{x}}
\frac{1}{n}$$
$$=O(\sqrt{x}\log(x))+2x-x\log(x)+2x(\log(x)-1)\big(\frac{\log(x)}{2}+\gamma+O(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})\big)$$
Thus we have:
$$\sum_{n\leq x}d(n)\log(n)=x\log(x)^2-2(1-\gamma)x\log(x)+2(1-\gamma)x+O(\sqrt{x}\log(x))$$

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the asymptotics of the divisor sum

$\sum_{n\le x} d(n)=x\log x+(2\gamma-1)x+O(\sqrt x)$

then you only need partial summation to include the weight $\log n$.

The divisor sum asymptotics is a classical application of Dirichlet's hyperbola method.

Indeed,

$\sum_{n\le x}d(n)=\sum_{mn\le x}1=\sum_{m\le\sqrt x}[\frac{x}{m}]+\sum_{n\le\sqrt x}[\frac{x}{n}]-[\sqrt x]^2$.

The first two terms on the RHS are the same; they are

$x\sum_{n\le \sqrt x}\frac{1}{x}+O(\sqrt x)=x(\log\sqrt x+\gamma+O(1/\sqrt x))$

and the third term is simply $x+O(\sqrt x)$.