# Abel Summation for d(n)/n

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, stieltjes-constants

If $d(n) = \sum_{d|n}1$ is the divisor function, it is a fact that $d$ has summatory behaviour
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n \leq x} d(n) = x \log x + (2 \gamma - 1)x + O(\sqrt{x}).
\end{equation}

I'm interested in the behaviour of $\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{d(n)}{n}$ for large $x$. Now, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471326/the-asymptotic-expansion-for-the-weighted-sum-of-divisors-sum-n-leq-x-frac?rq=1) uses the Dirichlet Hyperbola Method, which I understand, to get the result
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{d(n)}{n} = \frac{1}{2} \log^2 x + 2 \gamma \log x + \gamma^2 -2\gamma_1 + O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\right).
\end{equation}
However, if I try using Abel summation (motivated by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1175754/find-an-asymptotic-formula-for-sum-limits-n-leq-x-dn-log-n) similar question), I get the bound
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{d(n)}{n} = \frac{1}{x}\left(x \log x + (2 \gamma - 1) x + O(\sqrt x)\right) -1 + \int_1^x\frac{t \log t + (2 \gamma - 1) t + O(\sqrt t)}{t^2}dt
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=\frac{1}{2}\log^2 x + 2 \gamma\log x + 2(\gamma - 1) + O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt x} \right).
\end{equation}

Now the numerical constants $\gamma^2-2\gamma_1$ and $2(\gamma-1)$ are *not* equal; more worryingly I see no way that my approach could have yielded $\gamma_1$ leading me to believe the idea was fundamentally flawed. Would appreciate if someone could aide my understanding.

Comment: Perhaps $\gamma_1=-\gamma ^2-\int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}-\frac{1}{x}\right) e^{-x} \log (x) \, dx$ provides a clue.

Comment: An interesting relation. However per the selected answer it seems the best error I can do is $O(1)$ so unfortunately I wouldn't be able to use this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably made the following mistake:

$$\int_1^x \frac{O(\sqrt{t})}{t^2}\,dt = O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)$$

That's not right.

Observe that $$\int_1^x \frac{O(\sqrt{t})}{t^2}\,dt = O\left(\int_1^x \frac{\sqrt{t}}{t^2}\,dt\right)=O\left(2-\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}\right) = O(1)$$

which means that using Abel summation, the best approximation you can get is $$\sum_{n\le x} \frac{d(n)}{n} = \frac{1}{2}\log^2 x + 2 \gamma\log x + O(1)$$